# Probability that $X>Y$ under a bivariate copula model?

Tags: survival, references, copula

I am performing simulations from copula models in the context of Survival Analysis. Assuming that the random variable X represents the time of some event and Y represents censoring time. It would be nice to have explicit expressions for the censoring fraction: Prob{X>Y} for specific kind of copulas such as Clayton or Frank. In other words, I would like to derive Prob{X>Y} from the mathematical expression of the copula C(X,Y), not the general expression but for specific copulas e.g. Clayton and Frank and specific marginals e.g. Weibull.

Does anyone know if there are useful references to address this problem ? There are tons of papers about copulas and i have few knowledge of the theory.

Comment: The copula can't give you this information, because the actual values of the original data are lost in the transformation to the uniform marginals of the copula.

Comment: Sorry perhaps i wasn't clear enough. I would like to determine the probability by the mathematical expression of the copula. No data are involved. Now I'm going to revise the question.

Comment: [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40745-019-00197-5) adresses the specific problem of Clayton copula, Weibull marginals

Answer (score 1):

As already commented by @whuber, **the copula of $(X,Y)$ does not contain enough information to answer this question**. The copula only gives information about the dependence structure, but to compute $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \P(X > Y)$ information on the marginals in also necessary!

As an example, if $(X,Y)$ are independent random variables, then their coupla is the independence copula $C_{\text{Ind}}(x,y)=xy$, irrespective of the marginals. So, let $U,V$ be iid $\mathcal{Uniform}(0,1)$, then $\P(U>V)=\frac12$. Now, let $X,Y$ be independent, $X\sim\mathcal{Uniform}(0,1), Y\sim\mathcal{Uniform}(10,11)$, now $\P(X>Y)=0$, but they have the same copulas.

Comment: You're right explicit formulas can be given when also the marginals are specified. For example it would be nice to know the solution (if it exists) for Clayton Copula and Weibull Marginals. There are many possibilities. Perhaps there is some paper that addresses the problem and eventually gives solutions for some cases, but i am not able to find it (without screening a lot of papers).